# How do i use CheckBox in Python Kivy correctly

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

I need to write code so that it outputs a widget from three checkboxes. If I set a flag on one of the checkboxes, the other checkboxes should disappear. I was able to do this. But I want the checkbox to always be on one of the checkboxes, that is, it could not be removed permanently. Please tell me how I can do this. here is a piece of my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
class BooruScraperApp(App):   
    def build(self):
        choose_box = BoxLayout()
        def active_first(checkbox, value):
            if value:
                first_check.active = True
                second_check.active = False
                third_check.active = False
        def active_second(checkbox, value):
            if value:
                second_check.active = True
                first_check.active = False
                third_check.active = False
        def active_third(checkbox, value):          
            if value:
                third_check.active = True
                first_check.active = False
                second_check.active = False
        first_check = CheckBox(size_hint_x = .047, size_hint_y = .047, color = [0, 0, 0], active = True)
        second_check = CheckBox(size_hint_x = .047, size_hint_y = .047, color = [0, 0, 0])
        third_check = CheckBox(size_hint_x = .047, size_hint_y = .047, color = [0, 0, 0])
        first_check.bind(active = active_first)
        second_check.bind(active = active_second)
        third_check.bind(active = active_third)

        choose_box.add_widget(first_check)
        choose_box.add_widget(second_check)
        choose_box.add_widget(third_check)

        return choose_box

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BooruScraperApp().run()
```

Comment: You seem to be describing the behavior of radiobuttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: how can I use radiobuttons correctly?

Comment: I want the selection checkbox to remain always on one of the radiobuttons

Comment: I failed to understand exactly what you want to be happened. Could you please add more details ? What do you mean by 'disappear', 'removed permanently' ? Could the methods `remove_widget`, `clear_widgets` help ?

Comment: The answer to the question can be found at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600465/how-to-use-radiobutton-correctly-in-kivy-python/70601855#70601855