# How to use radiobutton correctly in kivy python?

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy, radio-button

I am using the radiobutton widget. I want the checkbox to always be on one of the radiobutton, meaning it cannot be permanently deleted. Please tell me how I can do this. here is a fragment of my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
class BooruScraperApp(App):   
    def build(self):

        choose_box = BoxLayout()
        first_check = CheckBox(group = 'test', size_hint_x = .047, size_hint_y = .047, color = [0, 0, 0], active = True)
        second_check = CheckBox(group = 'test', size_hint_x = .047, size_hint_y = .047, color = [0, 0, 0])
        third_check = CheckBox(group = 'test', size_hint_x = .047, size_hint_y = .047, color = [0, 0, 0])

        choose_box.add_widget(first_check)
        choose_box.add_widget(second_check)
        choose_box.add_widget(third_check)
        
        return choose_box

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BooruScraperApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [allow_no_selection](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.ToggleButtonBehavior.allow_no_selection) attribute:

```
    first_check = CheckBox(group='test', size_hint_x=.047, size_hint_y=.047, color=[0, 0, 0], active=True, allow_no_selection=False)
    second_check = CheckBox(group='test', size_hint_x=.047, size_hint_y=.047, color=[0, 0, 0], allow_no_selection=False)
    third_check = CheckBox(group='test', size_hint_x=.047, size_hint_y=.047, color=[0, 0, 0], allow_no_selection=False)
```